# Keep procedure running even connection dies?

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure in my database that is expected to sleep for very long periods of time, like 9 hours.

They perform some operations, sleep for hours, then do other stuff and exit.

I will be calling the procedure from a bash script or other means that I can integrate with `zabbix`.

Can I safely expect that the procedure will run even if the connections die, or any other timeouts that may apply to the SQL connection?

If this is not the correct approach to handle my situation please let me know the best way. I need to be sure that once this procedure is started, it will finish unless mariadb crashes.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to use the [`EVENT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/events/) system:

> Events are named database objects containing SQL statements that are to be executed at a later stage, either once off, or at regular intervals.
>
> They function very similarly to the Windows Task Scheduler or Unix cron jobs.

This should allow you to create tasks that are executed even if the client connection dies before it finishes. The only limitation is that you can't read the output of that command unless you store it in a table.

For example, if you have a stored procedure called `MyProc()`, you can call it with:

```sql
CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO
 CALL MyProc();
```

The reason this works is because the `ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` causes the event to trigger immediately after it has been created. Once the event execution is complete, the event is automatically deleted.

Usually you'd use this to delay the execution of some task but in this case we just want to offload the execution to the event subsystem in MariaDB.

---

The only problem you can run into is the uniqueness of the event names. As the execution is scheduled to take place immediately, it's probably not a problem in practice but it's good to keep in mind.

Another thing to take notice of is a limitation ([MDEV-18031](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18031)) in MariaDB that prevents events from being created inside stored procedures or compound statements.

Comment: This can't be a event because it has to be manually triggered

Comment: You can create a one-off event that is deleted once it has completed. I added an example of how it could be implemented.

Comment: @Freedo *This can't be a event because it has to be manually triggered* The user starts SP which performs immediate actions and creates an event which shoud be executed in 9 hours.

Comment: I can't use events. This is not a regular thing. It is not intended to be used in any way other than manually triggered by conditions outside of mysql/mariadb

Comment: @Freedo "*sleep for very long periods of time, like 9 hours*" - This conflicts with what you're saying in the comments, given this is a defined schedule. If this needs to be manually triggered, then what's the point of making the procedure sleep 9 hours?...just trigger the procedure 9 hours later, manually, again. Or let the application keep track of how long has passed since the first time it fired the procedure off, and then re-fire it again. Trying to make it sleep for 9 hours and hoping the connection doesn't get broken sounds like it's overcomplicating the process for no reason.

Comment: I can have the procedure create a event designed to run only once after 9 hours, but using events only is really not possible in my situation. Like I said i need this to run only if certain conditions happens that mariadb is not aware of. And it can run at any time, there is no schedule or way to predict this. I really need this to be something I call myself, when I want to, and only when I want to, with no way to make this a pure "event"

Comment: @Freedo you need to be more clear on your requirements, or what this procedure should do once the 9 hours are over. Why not do the logic in the bash script and then add a ´CREATE EVENT eventname ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 9 HOUR DO <whatever you want to do>;´?

Comment: because when I execute the procedure, I need some things to be done immediately, then other things to be done 9 hours after that. And I was trying to avoid using anything other than mysql. However if I can create a event from inside a procedure, that would be ok too

Comment: Unfortunately due to [MDEV-18031](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18031) it doesn't seem possible to create an event inside a stored procedure.